# if else variable condition jquery sent from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I create php program that send 'error login message' and send $_GET['error'] to html pages.

How to create jquery if else condition variable from php?

your answer will helpfuly.

```
URL : http://localhost:82/app/index.php?error=1
```

this my trying code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var loginError = <?php echo $_GET['error']; ?>;
   console.log(loginerror);


   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#div1").hide();

      if (loginError == 1) {
          $("#div1").show();
      }
   });  
</script>
```

I want to hide my div1 and div1 will show if url get $_GET['error'] variable

Can someone solve this? thanks for any help :D

Comment: what exactly do you want???

Comment: what's your error or problem with what you are trying?

Comment: `var loginError = "<?php echo $_GET['error']; ?>";`

Comment: unfortunately, jquery does not have if/else, you'll have to use plain ol' javascript

Comment: @OlegMeleshko: no need to add quotes

Comment: @devpro.. hmm. `Error login message` can't be parsed correctly by javascript, so quotes (especially if you're getting something from query string directly) are required.

Comment: @OlegMeleshko: error is equal to 1 means, integer, well it will work in both cases try it.

Comment: hide div1 and if url get error it show div1

Comment: @AVI: i think error have two values 1 and 0 if 1 show div else default hide..

Comment: what about this? console.log(loginerror); undefined

Comment: Remove this line `console.log(loginerror);` and change this line `var loginError = ...`, from `var loginError = <?php echo $_GET['error']; ?>;` to `var loginError = <?php echo isset($_GET['error']) ? 1 : 0; ?>;`

Comment: yeah it's work too. thankyou mr. Rajdeep Paul

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solve it, I write two script. It work when URL not get error variable, div1 will hide and when get error variable, div1 showing. Thanks all for help, especially mr.devpro, you're awesome

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#div1").hide();
        loginError = "";
        }); 
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var loginError = <?php echo $_GET['error']; ?>;  
        if (loginError == "1") {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#div1").show();
            }); 
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you want here, maybe you need to display a div when you have error == 1 in `$_GET`. If yes than you have an error in your client side scripting:

```
var loginError = <?php echo $_GET['error']; ?>;
console.log(loginerror);
```

Your variable name is `loginError` not `loginerror`, fix it your remaining code will execute as you need.

Currently, you will be getting this error in console:

> ReferenceError: loginerror is not defined

Comment: yes, I want to hide div1 at the first and show it when get url error. I dont know how to code it. My code did not work at all and div1 not hide too. thanks for reply

Comment: done, but still not work. div1 still showing. is my if else condition correct?

Comment: @AVI: check console for errors... if u r using firefox check in firebug console

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: @AVI: there are so many ways, but u need to check either your jquery working or not, check errors in console. if u r using firefox ,,, F12 and go to console.. and page refresh ... u will get the errors.

Comment: @AVI: if u r interested to debug use this, remove div hide show code and use alert(loginError);